# How to import XML data Using Java and store them into a Java List?

Tags: java, xml, list, import, store

How to import XML data Using Java and store them into a Java List ?

I want to import data from an XML file and Store them into a List Java , Any idea about that ?

i want to save the data into a list   `private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();`

My Xml file :

```
<trains>
  <train>
    <numTrain>TR123</numTrain>
    <villeDepart>Poitiers</villeDepart>
    <villeArrivee>Paris</villeArrivee>
    <heureDepart>1250</heureDepart>
  </train>
</trains>
```

My Code :

```
public class ReadXMLFile {


List<Train> trains = new ArrayList<Train>();



File fXmlFile = new File("/BookTrainRestWebServiceExercice2/src/main/java/soa/jaxrslabs/booktrainrestwebserviceexcercice2/TarinData.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);


doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("train");

System.out.println("----------------------------");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

    trains.add(new Train(eElement.getAttribute("numTrain"),
            eElement.getElementsByTagName("villeDepart").item(0).getTextContent(),
            "Ville d'arrivee : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("villeArrivee").item(0).getTextContent(),
            eElement.getElementsByTagName("heureDepart").item(0).getTextContent()));


        System.out.println("Tarin num : " + eElement.getAttribute("numTrain"));
        System.out.println("Ville de depart : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("villeDepart").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Ville d'arrivee : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("villeArrivee").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Heure de depart : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("heureDepart").item(0).getTextContent());

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many tutorials out there. One is this: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: @Tunaki , i want to store data into a java list not showing them in the console.

Comment: you read the data into java variables. What's stopping you from putting them in a list?

Comment: @f1sh , can u show me an exemple please ?

Comment: @f1sh , i edited my question so any idea about that now ?

Comment: you are done already, arent you? You put a ``Train`` object into your ``trains`` list.

Comment: @f1sh , no its not working :/